# A confusion on conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm confused on two kinds of conditional probabilities:

1. ${y=x+n}$, where ${x}=\pm1$ with equal probability(0.5).  And $n$ is $\cal{N}(0,1)$. Then I know, the conditional probability of ${y}$ conditional on ${x=1}$ is $\cal{N}(1,1)$, Which is formulated as:

$$f_{Y|X}(y|X=1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\displaystyle-\frac{(y-1)^2}{2}}$$

2. $y=x+n$, where $x, n$ are independent and $x$ is $\cal{N}(\mu,1)$, $n$ is $\cal{N}(0,1)$ as above.
   **It seems that**, given fixed $y$, $x=y-n$ is a Gaussian rv, and is $\cal{N}(y,1)$, which is formulated as:

$$f_{X|Y}(x|Y=y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\displaystyle\frac{(x-y)^2}{2}}$$

I know, the second statement is wrong, but I cannot figure out where I am wrong?

Comment: In your second case $y\sim N(\mu,2)$ and $n\sim N(0,1)$. Could you please illustrate how you are getting $X/Y=y\sim N(y,1)$?

Comment: The same argument as in statement 1, is statement 1 correct?

Comment: What is argument for the first case??

Comment: The flaw in the second argument is that $y$ and $n$ are not independent. The same argument, still forgetting the independence hypothesis, would show that if $y=0+n$ with $n$ standard normal then $0=y-n$ hence $0$ conditionally on $y$ is normal $N(y,1)$... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flaw in the second argument is that $y$ and $n$ are not independent. The same argument, still forgetting the independence hypothesis, would show that if $y=n$ with $n$ standard normal then the identity $0=y−n$ would imply that the distribution of $0$ conditionally on $y$ is normal $N(y,1)$ (instead of Dirac at $0$, the correct answer).

The correct statement is that, if $y=x+n$ with $n$ normal $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $x$ independent of $n$, then, condirionally on $x$, $y$ is normal $N(\mu+x,\sigma^2)$ (and the distribution of $x$ is irrelevant).

Thus the hypothesis that $x$ is independent of $n$ is missing from your 1.

*Exercise:* Assume that $y=x+n$ with $x$ and $n$ i.i.d. standard normal, then, conditionally on $y$, $x$ is normal with mean $\tfrac12y$ and variance $\tfrac12$.

Comment: Yes, you are right! thank you!